# Ajax/JS Does not go

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The script is nothing back what this could be?

Here a link to the page [Test Link](https://yadia.de/mein/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Anmeldung des Namens
    $("#startfrom").submit(function() {
        if($("#yourname").val() == "") {
            $("#response").html("Bitte gebe einen Namen an!");
        } else {
            name = $("#yourname").val();
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#response").html("Lade...");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chat.php"
                data: "name=" + name
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("main").html(msg);
                    $("#response").html("");
                    $("message").focus();
                }   
            });
        }   
        return false; 
    });
});
```

The code is intended to provide an issue who was entering no name.

Comment: First thing to do whenever some JS code is not working as you expect, check the console: `ajax.js:16 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Can clearly see the page reload because you haven't prevented default browser submit and have errors in code which can be seen in console

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you missed commas at the end of these lines:

```
url: "chat.php"
data: "name=" + name
```

These both lines need `,` in the end. They are objects. Corrected code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chat.php",
    data: "name=" + name,
    success: function(msg) {
        $("main").html(msg);
        $("#response").html("");
        $("message").focus();
    }   
});
```

The other mistake is: Change your form `id`: Your form id is `'startform'` not `'startfrom'`.

---

**Update**

[image]

Hope this above one helps you.

Works for me after **putting the comma**:

[image: Working]

Comment: I can't unfortunately also

Comment: @Lord Just post the link dude.

Comment: @Lord Change your form `id`: Your form id is `'startform'` not `'startfrom'`.

Comment: @Lord Only one comma you added. You forgot another comma.

Comment: @Lord Did you see your mistake in my answer? You have a comma missing after the `"chat.php"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form id is 'startform' and you wrote is 'startfrom'.

So, first of all correct you id name which you wrote in jquery and then try it.

After this if you got any error then try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Anmeldung des Namens
    $("#startform").submit(function() {
        if($("#yourname").val() == "") {
            $("#response").html("Bitte gebe einen Namen an!");
        } else {
            var name = $("#yourname").val();
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#response").html("Lade...");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "chat.php",
                data: { name: name},
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("main").html(msg);
                    $("#response").html("");
                    $("message").focus();
                }   
            });
        }   
        return false; 
    });
});
```

I hope you will get your solution.

Comment: <form id="startform" method="post">
      Dein Name:
   <input type="text" id="yourname" />
   <input type="submit" value="Chat beitreten" />
  </form>

Comment: Still can't and the ID is assigned

Comment: <form id="startfrom" method="post">
      Dein Name:
   <input type="text" id="yourname" />
   <input type="submit" value="Chat beitreten" />
  </form>

Comment: @Lord Did you see your mistake in my answer? I have pointed it out using red.